# C++ How to Auto Increment static integer variable on object creation?

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

C++ How to Auto Increment static integer variable on object creation?

When I run the program I want the account number to increment, and I am required to use a static member of the class to automatically assign numbers.

I am currently getting a make error for undefined reference to `bankAccount::accountNumber'

bankAccount.h

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

class bankAccount {
        string accountName;
        int accountNumber;
        string accountType;  //Checking or Savings.
        double accountBalance;
        double interestRate;

    public:
        static int nextAccNum;
        bankAccount();
        bankAccount(string accName, string accType, double accBalance, double intRate);
        void deposit();
        void withdraw();
        void display();
};
```

bankAccountImp.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bankAccount.h"

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

        bankAccount::bankAccount() {
            accountName = "";
            accountNumber = nextAccNum++;
            accountType = "";
            accountBalance = 0.00;
            interestRate = 0.00;
            accountNumber++;
        }
            
        bankAccount::bankAccount(string accName, string accType, double accBalance, double intRate) {
            accountName = accName;
            accountNumber = nextAccNum++;
            accountType = accType;
            accountBalance = accBalance;
            interestRate = intRate;
        }
        
        void bankAccount::deposit() {
            int depAmt;
            cout << "Please enter an amount to deposit: ";
            cin >> depAmt;
            accountBalance += depAmt;
        }
        
        void bankAccount::withdraw() {
            int delAmt;
            cout << "Please enter an amount to deposit: ";
            cin >> delAmt;
            accountBalance -= delAmt;
        }
        void bankAccount::display() {
            cout << "Account Number: " << accountNumber << endl;
            cout << "Holder's Name: " << accountName << endl;
            cout << "Account Type: " << accountType << endl;
            cout << "Interest Rate: " << interestRate << endl;
        }
```

The program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "bankAccount.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    bankAccount acct1;
    bankAccount acct2;
    
    acct1.display();
    cout << endl;
    acct2.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It does not increment because you are not doing any increments in default constructor.

Comment: I want to have each object of bankAccount have an individual bankAccount number, so acct1 has account number n, and acct2 has account number n+1...

Comment: there are two constructors. You increment in one but call the other

Comment: I have updated my original post where I put accountNumber++; in the default constructor, but acct1 gets account number 1 and acct2 gets account number 1 also.

Comment: @BlueWolf Your static variable is called `accNum` not `accountNumber`. It would help if you gave it a distinctive name like `nextAccNum`.

Comment: Why didn't you iinitialize the variable? On the first try, what are you incrementing? an uninitialized var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, I've renamed the static variable `nextAccNum`. Having one variable called `accNum` and another called `accountNumber` is obviously a recipe for confusion.

```
   bankAccount::bankAccount() {
        accountName = "";
        accountNumber = nextAccNum++;
        accountType = "";
        accountBalance = 0.00;
        interestRate = 0.00;
    }
        
    bankAccount::bankAccount(string accName, string accType, double accBalance, double intRate) {
        accountName = accName;
        accountNumber = nextAccNum++;
        accountType = accType;
        accountBalance = accBalance;
        interestRate = intRate;
    }
```

Comment: How do I declare "nextAccNum" in the default constructor, or do I need to declare it in the "bankAccount.h" ?

Comment: @BlueWolf I didn't mean to confuse you, You already have the correct code `public: static int accNum;` All I've done is rename `accNum` to `nextAccNum`. So rename the static variable you already have (or not if you prefer).

Comment: When I do that, make throws "undefined reference to `bankAccount::nextAccNum'"
I've updated my original post with my current code with your suggestions.

Comment: @BlueWolf Well that's a different problem. Add `int bankAccount::nextAccNum = 0;` to bankAccountImp.cpp (outside of any function). This is the normal way to define a static member variable.

Comment: Well, your a genius! Thanks you solved me problem 100% you need a raise!

Comment: @BlueWolf I'll take one, but unfortunately I'm retired.